# cant import class in javascript after renaming it

Tags: javascript, nxjs

I have a local library that exports a class called Foo, this is library is built into a module with [nx](https://nx.dev/) if that matters.

the file of the class looks like this (simplified)

```js
export class Foo {}
```

the index.js looks like this (simplified)

```js
export * from /path/to/foo/file
```

in my project i import it with

```js
import { Foo } from FooLib;
```

all of this works perfectly, no issues whatsoever

however this breaks if i rename the class in both files

```js
export class Bar {}
```

```js
import { Bar } from FooLib;
```

this results in node complaining

```
Error: export 'Bar' (imported as 'Bar') was not found in 'FooLib' (possible exports: Foo)
```

now this *looks* suspiciously like i did not rebuilt the library or forgot to install the new version but the lsp used by vscode recognizes the change, i can go to definition of the renamed class, which results in the appropriate file in node_modules.

also i can try to include Foo like before, which also fails

```js
import { Foo } from 'FooLib';
```

the corresponding error, is simmilar in tone but has different formatting

```
Module '"FooLib"' has no exported member 'Foo'.
```

renaming the class back to `Foo` fixes all those problems, meaning i can import the class under it's old name again, but I can't rename this class and have it work

I tried

- completely removing the node_modules of the project (and reinstalling the new FooLib)
- rebooting

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: this somehow resolved itself? letting this sit for 24 hours and rerunning it, somehow removed this issue (i did not interact with version control, and this is on a local machine in WSL)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are performing a clean build after renaming the class. Sometimes, residual artifacts from the previous build may cause unexpected issues. You can try running commands like npm clean or manually deleting the node_modules and dist directories before reinstalling and rebuilding.

Comment: completely deleting the node_modules of the project + deleting the dist folder + rebuilding, sadly did not help